# Open and print PDF files

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I'd like to open and print all PDF files located in a given folder. The files are named according to the following pattern:

```
NameOfThePrinter_Timestamp.pdf
```

Now I want to print those files using the corresponding printer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pdf = @"C:\PathToFolder";
    if (Directory.GetFiles(pdf).Length > 0)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pdf);
        var adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("App Paths").OpenSubKey("AcroRd32.exe");
        var path = adobe.GetValue("");
        string acrobat = path.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = acrobat;
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/p /s /h \"" + files[i] + "\"";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

            while (handle == IntPtr.Zero && DateTime.Now - start <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                } catch (Exception) { }
            }
            foreach (String verb in process.StartInfo.Verbs)
            {
                // Display the possible verbs.
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}. {1}", i.ToString(), verb);
                i++;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("File: " + files[i] + " is printing!");
            process.Kill();
        }

        foreach (string str in files)
        {
            File.Delete(str);
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Files are deleted!");
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I pass the printer name as parameter?

Here I've tried something, but it either throws and error or prints to the default printer:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/p /s /h \"" + files[i] + "\"";
```

Comment: This is not a german site, please translate to english so people can help you.

Comment: Hier auf Stackoverflow bitte ausschließlich auf Englisch schreiben! Please only write in english here on stackoverflow!

Comment: This question appears to be in German. 

Comment: I have tried to translate your question. You can always edit it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for translating Tim!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing A PDF Automatically to a specific printer and tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808125/printing-a-pdf-automatically-to-a-specific-printer-and-tray)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to send the PDF document to the printer.

Here you can find a sample how to send the PDF document to printer: [How to print PDF on default network printer using GhostScript (gswin32c.exe) shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599925/how-to-print-pdf-on-default-network-printer-using-ghostscript-gswin32c-exe-she)

And here you can find **Ghostscript wrapper for .NET** if you want to control Ghostscript directly without calling .exe file: **http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I tried it with no success but in my opinion GhostScript is the best way! I'll keep trying!! ;-)

Comment: UPDATE: GhostScript isn't the best way! :-D I read the instruction of the printer... It doesn't support GhostScript...

Answer (score -1):

```
 function printDisclosureDocument() {
            var doc = document.getElementById('pdfDocument');
            if (doc == 'undefined' || doc == null) {
                var pdfbox = document.createElement('embed');
                pdfbox.type = 'application/pdf';
                pdfbox.src = 'ShowPDF.aspx?refid=' + $('#MainContent_hdnRefId').val();
                pdfbox.width = '1';
                pdfbox.height = '1';
                pdfbox.id = 'pdfDocument';
                document.body.appendChild(pdfbox);
            }
            if (doc != null && doc != 'undefined') {
                //Wait until PDF is ready to print    
                if (typeof doc.print === 'undefined') {
                    setTimeout(function () { printDisclosureDocument(); }, 500);
                } else {

                    doc.print();
                }
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function () { printDisclosureDocument(); }, 500);
            }
        }
```